# MS Access: VBA SQL Update Query with Ampersand and Text

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-update, ampersand

I have a small syntax problem that I'm hoping someone will help me out with.
I need to run a query in MS Access VBA where the record descriptors in Column 2 are updated with two characters from the Left in Column 1 - AND - the text "On0".

I know there's a simple fix like a single apostrophe around a portion of the code, but I've hit a roadblock. Any thoughts?

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Update [Table1] SET [Table1].[New Col 2] = Left([Table1].[Old Col 1],2) & "On0";"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `DoCmd.RunSQL "Update [Table1] SET [Table1].[New Col 2] = Left([Table1].[Old Col 1],2) & 'On0';"`.  I've not added as an answer as not 100% sure.

Comment: I found it.  Yeah, It's just 'On0'.  Sorry about asking such a stupid question.

Comment: There's no stupid questions. :)  You can probably knock off the `;` at the end of the string to - Access isn't that strict about having it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Answer is to place a single apostrophe around the text so, the string should be as follows:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Update [Table1] SET [Table1].[New Col 2] = Left([Table1].[Old Col 1],2) & 'On0';"
```